# How to add swatch data in Layered navigation aggregations in graphql?

Tags: magento2.3, layered-navigation, swatches, graphql

How to add swatch data in Layered navigation aggregations in Graphql? Magento provides swatch data to filters [LayerFilter] but this is DEPRECATED so we use aggregations for the filter.

Below query is working

```
{
  products(filter: {category_id: {eq: "4"}}) {
    filters {
      name
      filter_items_count
      filter_items{
        label
        value_string
        items_count
        ... on SwatchLayerFilterItemInterface {
            swatch_data {
               type
               value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

For Aggregation filter layered navigation not working(Swatch Data)

```
{
  products(filter: {category_id: {eq: "4"}}) {
  aggregations {
    attribute_code
    count
    label
    options {
    label
    value
    count
      ...on SwatchLayerFilterItemInterface {
        swatch_data {
          type
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Anyone idea about this? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have override aggregations GraphQL API. Below code is working for me

> **File**:-Custom/Module/registration.php

```
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 
    'Custom_Module', 
    __DIR__);
```

> **File**:-Custom/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Store"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogInventory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> **File**: Custom/Module/etc/schema.graphqls

```
interface AggregationOptionInterface {
    swatch_data: SwatchData @doc(description: "Data required to render swatch filter item")
}
type SwatchData {
    type: String @doc(description: "Type of swatch filter item: 1 - text, 2 - image")
    value: String @doc(description: "Value for swatch item (text or image link)")
}
```

> **File**:-Custom/Module/etc/graphql/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilder" type="Custom\Module\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\DataProviderAggregationPlugin"/>
</config>
```

> **File**:-Custom/Module/DataProvider/Product/LayeredNavigation/DataProviderAggregationPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilder;
use Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class DataProviderAggregationPlugin extends LayerBuilder implements LayerBuilderInterface
{

    private $builders;
    protected $_logger;
    protected $eavConfig;
    private $swatchHelper;
    private $renderLayered;

    public function __construct(
        array $builders,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Config $eavConfig,
        Data $swatchHelper,
        RenderLayered $renderLayered
    )
    {
        $this->builders = $builders;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
        $this->renderLayered = $renderLayered;
    }

    public function build(
        AggregationInterface $aggregation,
        ?int $storeId
    ): array
    {
        $layers = [];
        foreach ($this->builders as $builder) {
            $layers[] = $builder->build($aggregation, $storeId);
        }
        $layers = \array_merge(...$layers);
        foreach ($layers as $key => $value) {
            $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $layers[$key]['attribute_code']);
            if ($this->swatchHelper->isSwatchAttribute($attribute)) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($layers[$key]['options']); $i++) {
                    $hashcodeData = $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId([$layers[$key]['options'][$i]['value']]);
                    $typeName = $this->getswatchType($hashcodeData[$layers[$key]['options'][$i]['value']]['type']);

                    $temp = [
                        'type' => $typeName,
                        'value' => $hashcodeData[$layers[$key]['options'][$i]['value']]['value']
                    ];

                    $layers[$key]['options'][$i]['swatch_data'] = $temp;
                }
            }
        }

        return \array_filter($layers);
    }

    public function getswatchType($valueType)
    {
        switch ($valueType) {
            case 0:
                return 'TextSwatchData';
            case 1:
                return 'ColorSwatchData';
            case 2:
                return 'ImageSwatchData';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**GraphQL Request:-**

```
{
  products(filter: {category_id: {eq: "2"}}) {
    aggregations {
      attribute_code
      count
      label
      options {
        label
        value
        count
        swatch_data{
          value
          type
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**GraphQL Response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "aggregations": [
        {
          "attribute_code": "color",
          "count": 7,
          "label": "Color",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "Red",
              "value": "5437",
              "count": 5,
              "swatch_data": {
                "value": "#eb0c0c",
                "type": "ColorSwatchData"
              }
            },
            {
              "label": "Blue",
              "value": "5438",
              "count": 3,
              "swatch_data": {
                "value": "#0d4aff",
                "type": "ColorSwatchData"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "attribute_code": "texture",
          "count": 6,
          "label": "Texture",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "model2",
              "value": "5432",
              "count": 5,
              "swatch_data": {
                "value": "/t/1/t1.jpeg",
                "type": "ImageSwatchData"
              }
            },
            {
              "label": "model3",
              "value": "5433",
              "count": 2,
              "swatch_data": {
                "value": "/t/3/t30.jpeg",
                "type": "ImageSwatchData"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below solution you will get the full path of a visual swatch of the image**

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/graphql/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilder">
        <plugin name="data-provider-aggregation-plugin"
                type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\DataProviderAggregationPlugin"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Plugin/DataProviderAggregationPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilder;
use Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilderInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media as SwatchesMedia;

class DataProviderAggregationPlugin extends LayerBuilder implements LayerBuilderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected LoggerInterface $_logger;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected Config $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private array $builders;

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private Data $swatchHelper;

    /**
     * @var RenderLayered
     */
    private RenderLayered $renderLayered;

    /**
     * @var SwatchesMedia
     */
    private SwatchesMedia $swatchMediaHelper;

    /**
     * @param array $builders
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param Data $swatchHelper
     * @param RenderLayered $renderLayered
     * @param SwatchesMedia $swatchMediaHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        array           $builders,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Config          $eavConfig,
        Data            $swatchHelper,
        RenderLayered   $renderLayered,
        SwatchesMedia   $swatchMediaHelper

    ) {
        parent::__construct($builders);
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
        $this->renderLayered = $renderLayered;
        $this->builders = $builders;
        $this->swatchMediaHelper = $swatchMediaHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param LayerBuilder $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregation
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterBuild(
        LayerBuilder         $subject,
        $result,
        AggregationInterface $aggregation,
        ?int                 $storeId
    ) {
        // Apply your custom logic here
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $result[$key]['attribute_code']);
            if ($this->swatchHelper->isSwatchAttribute($attribute)) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[$key]['options']); $i++) {
                    $optionId = [$result[$key]['options'][$i]['value']];
                    $hashcodeData = $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId($optionId);
                    $type = $hashcodeData[$result[$key]['options'][$i]['value']]['type'];
                    $value = $hashcodeData[$result[$key]['options'][$i]['value']]['value'];
                    $typeName = $this->getSwatchType($type);
                    $temp = ['type' => $typeName, 'value' => $value];
                    if ($type == Swatch::SWATCH_TYPE_VISUAL_IMAGE) {
                        $temp = [
                            'type' => $typeName,
                            'value' => $this->swatchMediaHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage(
                                Swatch::SWATCH_THUMBNAIL_NAME,
                                $value
                            )
                        ];
                    }
                    $result[$key]['options'][$i]['swatch_data'] = $temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return \array_filter($result);
    }


    /**
     * @param int $valueType
     * @return string
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getSwatchType(int $valueType): string
    {
        return match ($valueType) {
            Swatch::SWATCH_TYPE_TEXTUAL => 'TextSwatchData',
            Swatch::SWATCH_TYPE_VISUAL_COLOR => 'ColorSwatchData',
            Swatch::SWATCH_TYPE_VISUAL_IMAGE => 'ImageSwatchData',
            default => throw new LocalizedException(__('Unsupported swatch type')),
        };
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/schema.graphqls

```
interface AggregationOptionInterface {
    swatch_data: SwatchData @doc(description: "Data required to render swatch filter item")
}
type SwatchData {
    type: String @doc(description: "Type of swatch filter item: 1 - text, 2 - image")
    value: String @doc(description: "Value for swatch item (text or image link)")
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "attribute_code": "color",
  "label": "Color",
  "count": 6,
  "options": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "label": "Red",
      "value": "58",
      "swatch_data": {
        "value": "#ff0000",
        "type": "ColorSwatchData"
      }
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "label": "Shirt",
      "value": "219",
      "swatch_data": {
        "value": "https://test.com/media/attribute/swatch/swatch_thumb/110x90/m/b/Shirt.jpg",
        "type": "ImageSwatchData"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```